# reactjs how come my render keeps getting invoked a lot?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have have the following component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import RecipeItems from './RecipeItems';

class RecipeContainer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {

        };
    }
    loadRecipe()
    {
        fetch("http://localhost:64755/Api/recipe/" + this.props.recipeId)
        .then(result => {
            return result.json();
        })
        .then(data => {

            //const foo = data;
            this.setState({ Recipe: data })
        }
        )            
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
            return e;
        });
    }
    render() {
        this.loadRecipe()

            console.log('in recipecontainer');
            return(<div></div>)
    }
}

RecipeContainer.propTypes = {
    recipeId: PropTypes.number
};

export default RecipeContainer;
```

I originally put a console.log() for debugging but then I noticed this method is being call in what it seems is a loop. It doesn't stop. What is wrong here? I know when I remove this.setState({ Recipe: data }) then the loop stops.

Comment: Never, *ever* create side-effects in your `render()` method. It should just be a pure result of props and state. To be extra clear, in your render method, you should read your props and state and return an element. nothing else. React can call the render method for any number of reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a `fetch` call in your `render` method. This call updates the `state` of the component using `this.setstate`, which triggers a call to `render` and so on. This is why you see the `console.log` statement in a loop.

You should `fetch` data in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to prevent this type of infinite loop. `componentDidMount` will be called only after `render` finishes running the first time and there is no chance of the infinite loop of calls.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import RecipeItems from './RecipeItems';

class RecipeContainer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            Recipe: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("http://localhost:64755/Api/recipe/" + this.props.recipeId)
        .then(result => {
            return result.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ Recipe: data });
        })                    
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            return e;
        });
    }
    render() {    
            console.log('in recipecontainer');
            return(<div></div>);
    }
}

RecipeContainer.propTypes = {
    recipeId: PropTypes.number
};

export default RecipeContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt run anything apart from rendering html code in your render function. So move the `this.loadRecipe` to your componentDidMount function and see if that helps.

also here is the right syntax for your ajax call:

```
fetch("http://localhost:64755/Api/recipe/" + this.props.recipeId)
    .then(result => {
        this.setState({ Recipe: result.json() })
    })           
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

also you can set defultProps within your class, like so:

```
class RecipeContainer extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
       ...defaultprops
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Making network calls in the constructor is not a good idea. As per the react docs, it is better to do it in `componentDidMount`. I guess this is because if the component is unmounted and remounted, the data will not refresh if it is called in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

its a loop. render method will be called whenever there is a change in props or state. in your case you are calling the loadRecipe(). which updates the state. causes re execution of render, again calls loadRecipe() . so this will an endless loop. insted you can call the loadRecipe in some lifecycle method. say componentDidMount().

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import RecipeItems from './RecipeItems';

class RecipeContainer extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

    };
}
componentDidMount(){
  this.loadRecipe() // will be called only once. 
  // thus the state will be updated once by this function.

}
loadRecipe()
{
    fetch("http://localhost:64755/Api/recipe/" + this.props.recipeId)
    .then(result => {
        return result.json();
    })
    .then(data => {

        //const foo = data;
        this.setState({ Recipe: data })
    }
    )            
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
        return e;
    });
}
render() {


        console.log('in recipecontainer');
        return(<div></div>)
       }
   }

RecipeContainer.propTypes = {
    recipeId: PropTypes.number
};

export default RecipeContainer;
```

Comment: I had trimmed out my code a bit to illustrate my problem but the situation was that when this component renders I wanted it to do a fetch whenever it's recipeId changed. If I put the fetch in componentDidMount it would only work one time I need it to fetch whenever the ID changed. What do you recommend?

Comment: if ( this.props.recipeId) is your source for the id and it changes. then you can use componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) hook to look for the change. this will be called everytime your props change. you can call fetch from here also